# How do I automatically change method/class access levels in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, access-modifiers

A lot of the time, I start out with methods being `public` and then reducing them to the lowest levels needed after I finish, but that's kind of tedious. Is there a way to automatically change all the privacy modifiers (for both classes and methods) to the lowest ones possible all at once?

Comment: AFAIK no. Can't you just use the correct visibility from the beginning?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible: Analyze | [Run inspection by name](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-inspection-by-name.html), and enter **Declaration access can be weaker** name for the inspection. Then run the inspection for the project and [fix all the occurrences](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/applying-quickfixes-automatically.html) in the project by one click in [Inspection results tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inspection-results-tool-window.html).

Answer (score 1):

To change generated methods default access modifier:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation -> Default Visibility

There is a different setting for classes:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates